# Find a number of occurrences of character in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string and I want to remove the first 3 occurrences of the letter `a` (for example).

Seems regex has no solution for a specific number of occurrences. And I can't use `replace` without loops, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Is 3 a variable number?

Comment: Can you give some examples ?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid "loops"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice challenge.

This works:

```js
var str = "I have a string and I want to remove the first 3 occurrences of the letter a (for example).";
str = str.replace(/^([^a]*a){3}/, function(match) {
  return match.replace(/a/g, '!');
});
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Result:

```
I h!ve ! string !nd I want to remove the first 3 occurrences of the letter a (for example).
```

The first `replace` matches a continuous string containing exactly 3 `a`s. Its inner replace changes the `a` to a `!` for clarity; you can safely replace it with nothing as well.

This is scaleable to any number because you can change the `{3}` to the required number of changes.

Comment: ▲ I was thinking of similar two step solution.

Comment: @Jai: ah it's all in lateral thinking. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2):

> I have a string and I want to remove the first 3 occurrences of the
>   letter a (for example).

If regex is not mandatory and looping is not a huge concern, then try this single line loop

```
str = str.split(/(?=a)/).map(function(value,index){ if (index < 3){value=value.replace("a", "")} return value }).join(""); // 3 and "a" can be passed on as input
```

make it a function like this

```js
    function removeNOccurences(str, toBeRepalced, n)
    {
       return str.split(/(?=a)/).map(function(value,index){ if (index < n){value=value.replace(toBeRepalced, "")} return value }).join("");
    }
    
    document.body.innerHTML += removeNOccurences("asdas3sdfw3aar23rzas", "a", 3);
```

Comment: _And I can't use replace without loops, which I want to avoid._....This is awkward actually.

Comment: @Jai what do you mean by awkward?

Comment: @Jai true, have updated the answer to include a disclaimer :). but the code works not sure how it warrants a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which utilises the `thisArg` of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var string = 'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a'.split('').filter(function (a) {
    return a !== 'a' || ++this.c > 3;
}, { c: 0 }).join('');

document.write(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

With replace callback counting the matches:

```js
function replaceFirstN(str, regex, n, replacement) {
  var i = 0;
  return str.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return i++ < n ? replacement : match;
  });
}

output.innerText = replaceFirstN("a a a a a a a a", /a/g, 3, "b");
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `Loop`, `String#replace` and `regex`

```js
var str = "abcabcabcabc";

function replace(s, symbol, replacer, times) {
    if (times == 0) return s;
    var i = s.indexOf(symbol);
    var a = s.split('');
    a[i] = replacer;
    return replace(a.join(''), symbol, replacer, --times)
}

var result = replace(str, 'a', '_', 3);

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "What a beautiful day is today";
var strA = str.split('a',4).join('a');
var strRemaining = str.replace(strA,'');

// Do global replace and append remaining string
var resultStr = strA.replace(/a/g,'') + strRemaining; 
alert(resultStr);
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9gg4nnvL/)